# Android - How can I get the email from the online login and show it to next intent

Tags: android-asynctask

I created an online login on my mobile app, basically I have an online database, and I use asynctask for login. Basically I want to display the email that the user input from the app and display it to the next intent how can I do that, How can I pass the email that the user input to onPostExecute?

Here is the code in the onPostExecute when the user successfully logged in.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    if (result.equals("Login Successfully!")) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome to OKShop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main2Activity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);

        ((Activity)context).finish();
    }
}
```

And here is the login URL

```
else if (type.equals("login")) {

        String email = params[1];
        String password = params[2];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```